# Using Two Tables with the WHERE clause from two databases

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables from two different databases. **TableA (database-1)** and **TableB (database-2)**. **TableA** has three attributes (student_id, semester, account_status) and **TableB** has two attributes **(student_id, assesor_status)**. How do i connect to both databases at the same time and get to pull out the data from both tables and have it counted to giving me the **sum of all student_id** which have an **account_status value 'ACTIVE' and semeter value '6' and assesor_status with value 'PENDING**'

This is what i did but im failing to connect to both databases at the same time.

```
SELECT (COUNT)TableA.student_id 
FROM TableA, TableB 
WHERE semester = '6' 
    AND account_status = 'ACTIVE' 
    AND assesor_status = 'PENDING';
```

Comment: 1. Does your DBs are placed on one server? 2. Are you using one connection to communicate with both DBs?

Comment: yes both databases are on one server

Comment: and im using two connections to connect each sql statement using require("database-1");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using one connection to access both DBs you could

```
SELECT COUNT(a.student_id) 
FROM DBA.TableA a
INNER JOIN DBB.TableB b ON a.student_id = b.student_id 
WHERE     a.account_status = 'AVTIVE' 
      AND a.semesteer = '6' 
      AND b.assesor_status = 'PENDING'
```

Otherwise you you could use two queries

```
SELECT b.student_id 
FROM TableA b 
WHERE b.assesor_status = 'PENDING'
```

Then use result with `IN`

```
SELECT COUNT(a.student_id) 
FROM TableA a
WHERE a.student_id IN(?) -- result from previous query
      AND a.account_status = 'AVTIVE' 
      AND a.semesteer = '6'
```

Comment: based on the first option since i have both databases in the same server how can i get to connect to both databases at the same time. I use this at the moment <?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="l1mk0admin"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="database-1"; // Database name
?> and the same applies for database-2

Answer (score -1):

**Syntactical Error**

You are missing the table names in the WHERE clause. `semester`,`account` and `assesor_status` columns should be in some table. Add the table name like you have done for `student_id` column.

**Logical Error**

Also, I don't see the relation between `TABLEA` and `TABLEB` defined in your query. You should add that to get expected results